# Is there a way to draw less memory expensive trails?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I posted this question on Unity Answers, without luck so far, so I thought I would give it a go here as well.

I'm working on a project involving an AI agent to be trained to navigate around a environment, and I want to visualise how the movement pattern change as training progresses. I started out by using the build-in component TrailRenderer but the inclusion of jumps, from where the current training session ends to the start position, annoyed me and and so I wrote my own custom implementation.

I wanted my implementation to have three abilities; The possibility to restrict the number of trails visible, changing alpha on the trails drawn based on their relevance and to not include jumps, as when using the TrailRenderer component.

The implementation is shown, and elaborated on, below but I think it make sense to outline the biggest hurtle before digging in to the implementation.

The biggest hurtle of my own implementation at the moment, as I see it, is that some of the trails can end up consisting of a huge number of points (maximum number of points witness so far are 30000+), if the environment is challenging enough, which slows down the training tremendously. I have no idea how to improve on that hurtle, other than adding a time delay, such that a new point is only added every, let's say, 0.5 second. However, larger time delays results in greater inaccuracy in the visualised trails, and so constrains the value the trails provide.

Training (500000 steps) takes, without trail drawing, around 45 minutes on my machine. With my implementation for drawing trails, and 0.5 seconds time delay, 220000 training steps takes around 1.5 hour, after which I decided to stop training.

My implementation consists of two parts; A script, which is attached to the agent, which draws the current trail, with the possibility of adding a time delay. The second part is not a script itself but a part of the AgentReset() method, which has two purposes; Adding/Removing trails at run time and changing alpha of the trails, depending on how relevant they are, i.e. newest trails has highest alpha.

Below is the script attached to the agent,

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class drawDynamicTrail : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private GameObject[] trails;
     private int traceStep = 0;
     private int traceNumber = 0;
     private int currentTrace;
     private LineRenderer lr;
     private float timeToDraw = 0;
     public bool drawTrails = false;

     void Update()
     {
       if (drawTrails){
         if (Time.time > timeToDraw)
         {
           trails = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Trail");

           if (trails.Length != traceNumber)
           {
             traceNumber = trails.Length;
             traceStep = 0;
           } else
           {
             currentTrace = traceNumber - 1;
             lr = trails[currentTrace].GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

             if (traceStep >= lr.positionCount)
             {
               lr.positionCount = traceStep + 1;
             }
             lr.SetPosition(traceStep,transform.position);
             traceStep += 1;
           }
           timeToDraw = Time.time + 0.5f;
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

I'm happy to provide the entire AgentReset() method if needed, but it is left out for now, as I believe that part isn't the origin of the challenge.

All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

General performance tip: Avoid usage of "FindGameobject..." inside of "Update" if possible. In your case, I guess the list of trails is growing, so you NEED to update it, right?

Ideas:

- make `trails` public or define a `addTrail` method - add trails whenever you create new "Trail"-tagged objects. This should be faster, as "FindGameobject..." will take longer and longer, the more objects you have in scene.
- Are you actually interested in ALL trails? Or do the most recent ones suffice? If you want to draw only the latest trails, think about the new [Ringbuffer mode](https://unity3d.com/how-to/flexible-and-performant-Particle-Systems)
- Old trails won't change right? Does your camera move? If not, you may draw the trails in a texture, so you only draw new trails above the old, no need to redraw old trails. Except for re-drawing the texture. But this is **memory-constant**.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas @KYL3R!
I'll try to work with them, and update you on the result.
One question, since you don't touch upon that at all: Isn't the growing size of the trails a concern, or am I putting too much attention on that?

Comment: I  just went over your suggestions, and here are my initial thoughts:
1: The number of trails are for the most of the time the same number, specified by the user. Let's say I would like to see 50 trails at a time, then the number of trails changes (increases) until 50 trails has been drawn, after which the oldest trail is removed and a new one is added, maintaining the number of trails at 50 for the rest of the training. So, ```trails``` are called to update the list, but I agree that it should be in the Update call.
I'm not interested in all trails, only the last 50, in this example.

Comment: That really sounds like a ringbuffer. Or basically a fixed-size object pool. If you FindGameobjects is still slow, if you have a lot of objects in the scene. Try to reuse the 50 trails, change their path instead of creating and deleting them again and again. Drawing only 50 should give you a speed up and save memory.
In the end, use the Profiler to see what is taking long.